# Cuando ejecuto mi Jframe en neatbeans no puedo visualizarlo

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

el dia de ayer mi proyecto funcionaba pero el dia de ahora cuando lo intente ejecutar solo menciona "Scanning for project" y no me muestra nada grafico.

Seria de gran ayuda si me pueden ayudar porque intente todo lo que pude encontrar...

Gracias.

Comment: Es importante revisar el Log de Netbeans, agrega que error se muestra. Revisar [ask], saludos.